# More services like Temboo or Webshell.io?

Tags: web-services, api, rest

Temboo and Webshell.io normalizes the API access of multiple API Providers like twitter, tumblr, facebook, twilio etc...

Does anyone know how to name this kind of services ? If you had to search them for how you would have tag them ? an API SDK ? an API Combinator ? API Wrapper ? API Integrator ? API Middleware maybe ¿?

**Anyone know more sites like Temboo or Webshell.io ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're called API middlewares.
Webshell.io calls itself an "API combinator".
Another service you might want to check out is "Yahoo! Pipes".